# Can't remove layout blocks. (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, xml, magento-2.1

**Information:** I'm using Magento 2.1 on CentOS Linux, my theme is a child of the built-in Luma theme.

When the theme I made is active, I want some blocks to be removed. Let's say I want to remove the SKU number from the product page.

**What I do is:**

- In my theme folder, I add a file called `Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`, with the following content

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
      <body>
          <referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true" />
      </body>
  </page>
  ```
- I change the `version` in `composer.json` from `100.x.0` to `100.(x+1).0` (so for example if the current version is `100.2.0` I change it to `100.3.0`). To be honest, don't really know if this is necessary.
- I delete the `<theme-name>` folders from `pub/static/frontend/<theme-vendor>` and `var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/<theme-vendor>`.
- I run the following commands from the Magento root:

  ```
  sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
  sudo chown -R <user-of-Magento>:<group-of-that-user> *
  sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL en_US
  sudo chown -R <user-of-Magento>:<group-of-that-user> *
  ```

But the block is still there! Unchanged. I tried other blocks, like the add to cart button, but also without success.

**What should I do? Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1):

Try following code

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" display="false" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Thanks, but still nothing. :(

Comment: This worked for me but I need to wrap with `columns` instead of `content`.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the var directory and then run `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Answer (score 0):

Your name of that block is wrong :)

You should use this correct name:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.stock.sku" remove="true"/>
```

Then run:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Don't run `setup:upgrade` for a simple XML change. This could cause a lot of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true" />
```

You don't need to change your composer.json or delete the static folders or change permissions or run the static content deployment.

You just have to clear the cache `bin/magento cache:clean` and see the changes. If it doesn't work you can try:

- Check the browser cache (it's often just that)
- Clear the cache manually. Delete the content of the var/cache folder
- Make sure you are working on the right theme. Write something in a .phtml file as a test.